# CASE statement not providing needed answer

Tags: sql, date, case, teradata, between

I have a very large table that shows a daily record of products and event types.  I am open on rearranging how the query is written below, but thought the case statement would supply me with the necessary output.

Table_1:

```
DATES      PRODUCT  EVENT
5/20/2017   APPLE   SALE
5/21/2017   APPLE   SALE
5/22/2017   APPLE   SALE
5/23/2017   APPLE   SALE
5/24/2017   APPLE   SALE
5/25/2017   APPLE   SALE
5/26/2017   APPLE   SALE
5/27/2017   APPLE   FULL PRICE
5/28/2017   APPLE   FULL PRICE
5/29/2017   APPLE   FULL PRICE
5/30/2017   APPLE   FULL PRICE
5/31/2017   APPLE   FULL PRICE
6/1/2017    APPLE   FULL PRICE
6/2/2017    APPLE   FULL PRICE
6/3/2017    APPLE   FULL PRICE
6/4/2017    APPLE   FULL PRICE
6/5/2017    APPLE   FULL PRICE
6/6/2017    APPLE   FULL PRICE
6/7/2017    APPLE   LIQUIDATION
6/8/2017    APPLE   LIQUIDATION
6/9/2017    APPLE   LIQUIDATION
6/10/2017   APPLE   LIQUIDATION
6/11/2017   APPLE   LIQUIDATION
6/12/2017   APPLE   LIQUIDATION
6/13/2017   APPLE   LIQUIDATION
6/14/2017   APPLE   LIQUIDATION
5/20/2017   BANANA  SALE
5/21/2017   BANANA  SALE
5/22/2017   BANANA  SALE
5/23/2017   BANANA  SALE
5/24/2017   BANANA  SALE
5/25/2017   BANANA  SALE
5/26/2017   BANANA  SALE
5/27/2017   BANANA  SALE
5/28/2017   BANANA  SALE
5/29/2017   BANANA  SALE
5/30/2017   BANANA  FULL PRICE
5/31/2017   BANANA  FULL PRICE
6/1/2017    BANANA  FULL PRICE
6/2/2017    BANANA  FULL PRICE
6/3/2017    BANANA  FULL PRICE
6/4/2017    BANANA  FULL PRICE
6/5/2017    BANANA  FULL PRICE
6/6/2017    BANANA  FULL PRICE
6/7/2017    BANANA  FULL PRICE
6/8/2017    BANANA  FULL PRICE
6/9/2017    BANANA  FULL PRICE
6/10/2017   BANANA  FULL PRICE
6/11/2017   BANANA  FULL PRICE
6/12/2017   BANANA  FULL PRICE
6/13/2017   BANANA  FULL PRICE
6/14/2017   BANANA  FULL PRICE
```

Current Query:

```
select
    product,
    case when event in ('liquidation') then 'yes' else 'no' end LIQ,
    count(dates) as days
FROM TABLE_1
where dates between '5/20/2017' and '6/14/2017'
group by
    product
```

I want a single record by product and yes/no if it was in liquidation during the date range.  This query executes, but gives the following results:

```
PRODUCT   LIQ         DAYS
APPLE     NO           18
APPLE     YES           8
BANANA    NO           26
```

I am looking for a simple yes or no if a product was in liquidation between dates 5/20/2017 and 6/14/2017.  Here is what I am looking for:

```
PRODUCT    LIQ        DAYS
APPLE      YES         26
BANANA     NO          26
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following uses the property of "yes" and "no" that "yes" > "no":

```
select product,
       max(case when event in ('liquidation') then 'yes' else 'no' end) as LIQ,
       count(dates) as days
from TABLE_1
where dates between '2017-05-20' and '2017-06-14'
group by product;
```